# jasperreport Export CSV Performance

Tags: java, csv, jasper-reports

I'm using japserreport to export data from a query to CSV (`;` separated). The report is created dynamically as i don't know in advance the query i'm going to execute.

I start with an "empty" jrxml file `reportFileName` (empty without any section,  with only datasource).

```
    final JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFileName);
```

I dynamically add `JRDesignField` according to the fields I have:

```
    final JRDesignField field = new JRDesignField();
    field.setName(value);
    field.setValueClass(java.lang.String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);
```

I have a title and detail bands:

```
    final JRDesignBand titleBand = new JRDesignBand();
    titleBand.setHeight(20);
    final JRDesignBand detailBand = new JRDesignBand();
    detailBand.setHeight(20);
```

to which i add static text:

```
    final JRDesignStaticText staticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
    staticText.setText(label);
    staticText.setX(x);
    staticText.setWidth(100);
    staticText.setHeight(20);
    titleBand.addElement(staticText);
```

and fields:

```
    final JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setX(x);
    textField.setWidth(100);
    textField.setHeight(20);
    final JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setValueClass(java.lang.String.class);
    expression.setText("$F{" + value + "}");
    textField.setExpression(expression);
    detailBand.addElement(textField);
```

and then I export the report to CSV format:

```
    final JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JRAbstractExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRCsvExporterParameter.FIELD_DELIMITER, ";");
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.PROGRESS_MONITOR, progressMonitor);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

Now the export works fine, and i can see my generated `CSV` file with correct columns and values.

My problem is:

- When i run jasperreport in `TRACE` mode, i can see that it calculates a whole bunch of text widths and heights, this is OK for all kinds of exports but it's unnecessary for CVS files (flat files). How can I tell jasper not to make all these calculations ? (I use a `JRSwapFileVirtualizer` and the swapfile is now over 1GB and counting for 300k records)

I'm using jasperreport 4.5.1